# How to insert into big CLOB string

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I am trying to insert data from CLOB which size exceeds 4000 characters, and when attempting to run the following SQL script:

```
insert into cleared_data (fdata)
select cleared_data_seq.nextval,
    dbms_lob.substr(dd.fdata, dbms_lob.instr(dd.fdata,'sign')-13,9)
from dirty_data dd
```

it gives error

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: : character string buffer too small
```

I want to cut the string which starts from 9th character and ends with character before the word 'sign'. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Add structures of source and target tables to post.

Comment: And one more thing: you have one field in insert statement and 2 in select

Comment: How long is the resulting string going to be - what does `dbms_lob.instr(dd.fdata,'sign')-13` evaluate to? What is the data type and size of `fdata`? If the substring is more than 4000 characters, or the size of `fdata`, for any row that matches your filter on `dd` (which isn't shown) then this error would be expected. What would you want to do with a substring that was too long - skip it, truncate it?